# Edit points not reflecting in total since last 7 days

Tags: support, edits, reputation

On Stack Overflow, I've edited 3 posts in the last 7 days or so, the corresponding reputation points for reflection in my reputation timeline but the same are not reflecting in reputation total.

I know that there are multiple reasons when reputation points are not rewards namely:

1. **reached the daily limit?** No, haven't reached that
2. **reached the global edit limit of 2000 edit ?** No have only edit 37 posts till date
3. **editing is reverted?** no edit was accepted for all case
4. **received a down vote, which  negated the edit reputation points gained?** NO, I've not received any down votes
5. **Posts are deleted?** No out of the 3 post`s edited 1 is on-hold other two are very much active

how can I find out why the reputation points not reflecting in the total?
Have i missed a reason or two which could be the reason for not getting the points?

Comment: You can earn points by editing posts?

Comment: @IvankaTodorova : yes you can :)

Comment: @IvankaTodorova you gain 2 points for each accepted suggested edit. I guess once you have passed 2k and can edit freely you no longer gain the points.

Comment: @Bugs when you pass 2k reputation points or 2k posts edited?

Comment: @Bugs Correct. You only get points for edits that are accepted. You'll still get points for tag wiki edits, as these are reviewed until you have 20k rep. Also, IIRC the maximum amount of rep for edits is 1000; after making 1000 points on edits, even suggested edits that were accepted will no longer give you points.

Comment: @IvankaTodorova rep. Sorry I should have made that clearer. S.L. Barth has provided further clarification.

Comment: @IvankaTodorova 2k rep. After that you get full edit privileges; your edits will no longer be reviewed, so you're not getting points for them either.

Comment: [It is "Stack Overflow", not "stackoverflow"](http://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance) (the last section, "Proper Use of the Stack Exchange Name"). Please edit your question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Api `/2.2/users/{id}/reputation-history/full?site=stackoverflow'`

i got the following result

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "reputation_history_type": "post_deleted",
      "reputation_change": -2,
      "post_id": 41476741,
      "creation_date": 1486225421,
      "user_id": @user_id
    },
    {
      "reputation_history_type": "suggested_edit_approval_received",
      "reputation_change": 2,
      "post_id": 42032960,
      "creation_date": 1486189908,
      "user_id": @user_id
    },
    {
      "reputation_history_type": "post_deleted",
      "reputation_change": -2,
      "post_id": 41457400,
      "creation_date": 1486090846,
      "user_id": @user_id
    },
    {
      "reputation_history_type": "post_deleted",
      "reputation_change": -2,
      "post_id": 41829612,
      "creation_date": 1486090846,
      "user_id": @user_id
    },
    {
      "reputation_history_type": "suggested_edit_approval_received",
      "reputation_change": 2,
      "post_id": 42002607,
      "creation_date": 1486047889,
      "user_id": @user_id
    },
    ....
]}
```

as you can see on same dates there are feeds with "reputation_history_type": "post_deleted", results in -2 reputation change. these feeds have post_id i.e ids of post that I had edit on some previous date

Concluding that the reputation gained via editing post was lost due to these post delete

**Point to Note:** `post_delete` feeds are not displayed in the reputation timeline UI

Image below shows my reputation feed : please notice no negative feeds shown

[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to your [profile history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/379054/crazyshezy?tab=reputation) you got 6 reputation point for edits in the last few days, what do you believe your reputation should be?

[image]

Comment: my total should be 931

Comment: @Crazyshezy do you have any proof of this?

Comment: I don't have proof .. how can i get proof for something like this?

Comment: on a side note? the 3 upvotes on this question is also not reflected anywhere

Comment: @Crazyshezy meta votes don't give you reputation, they are just for the community to show agreement / disagreement with your post.

Comment: Ok got that.. but no proof for total

Comment: @Crazyshezy take a look at something like this: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/624337

Comment: ok i guess I figured out,   using the api `/2.2/users/{id}/reputation-history/full?site=stackoverflow'`
i noticed that some posts which I had previously edited got deleted on the same days, I lost the reputation i gained..

Comment: @Crazyshezy In your reputation tab on your profile, you should see all reputation gains and losses, including from posts that get deleted.

Comment: @TylerH : I have added an image below in my answer please have a look

Comment: @Crazyshezy at the bottom of the list of reputation changes, is a "show removed posts" checkbox.